# Adding a number from a database to an existing variable to perform a query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am not sure if this is possible to do without doing a query first.

I have something like this:

```
$item_weight
```

This item goes into a box, which has its own row `$box->weight` and has a max weight `$box->max_weight`.

I want a list of boxes that I could put my item into.

I know I can do this by doing a query first and then calculating with a `foreach` but I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Something like this:

```
$boxes= Boxes::where('max_weight','>',$item_weight + $box->weight)
                ->orderBy('max_weight','asc')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [whereRaw](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/99469b6499c1e404c78a70c9c58812c7da5f45ec/Query/Builder.php#L705) and shift calculation to db side:

```
$boxes= Boxes::whereRaw('boxes.max_weight - boxes.weight > ?', [$item_weight])
    ->orderBy('max_weight','asc')
    ->get();
```